# is there a way to get the part item in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<ul id="test">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

now,is there a way to get the part item eg:`from 2---8`in jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
$('#test li').slice(1, 8);
```

1 because parameters is zero based http://api.jquery.com/slice/

Comment: Indeed, the arguments are zero-based, so it should be `slice(1, 8)` if you want to return `2..8` (from second to eighth div, inclusive).

Comment: @ Frédéric Hamidi: i accidentally upvoted your comment `.slice( start, [end] )` doesn't say anything about end being inclusive?

Comment: @naveen, `end` is *not* inclusive, I was referring to the actual slice of `<div>` elements: we want a slice from the second to the eighth `<div>`, *including the eighth `<div>`*. So we should start from index `1` (the second div) and stop before processing index `8` (the ninth `<div>`).

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [jQuery.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

*Reduce the set of matched elements to a subset specified by a range of indices.*